# With Python 3, how to write() 8-bit unsigned integers with high bit 1, as 1 byte?

Tags: python

I am using `python3`.  I want to `write()` all 8-bit unsigned integers as 1 byte to a subprocess - let me show you what I mean:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["./some_program"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> x=0x80
>>> p.stdin.write(str.encode(chr(x)))
2
```

This is no good, I want to output 1 byte, not 2.  I guess this is because the default encoding is utf-8.  OK, I try

```
>>> p.stdin.write(str.encode(chr(x), "ascii"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\x80' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Certainly, no good either.

What do I put after `p.stdin` in order to send just 1 byte to the subprocess, for all unsigned integers from `'\x00'` to `'\xff'` , exactly 1 byte with bits just like the 8-bit representation of the integer?

Comment: Try to write `b'\x80'`.

Comment: @KlausD.  yes, so the problem is, the `'\x80'` is really not a literal string, but an output from another method - I tried to write an SSCCE, maybe too hard.

Comment: @KlausD. OK I updated the question, please take a look now.

Comment: Are you trying to write binary data to stdin which is in text mode?  You should be writing to the buffer. `p.stdin.buffer.write(b'\x80')`

Comment: @JeffMercado well I used `cat` as an example, did not know it mattered.  What I have in there, is another program, compiled by me from C, to accept stuff on `stdin`.

Comment: Again... python will open stdin in _text mode_ but you want to write binary data. An "8-bit unsigned integer" is not text, you should write it as-is, as binary data.

Comment: @JeffMercado Please bear with me, yes exactly, you are exactly hitting my point, thank you - so how do I write it "as-is"?? That is what I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["cat"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
x = 0x80
p.stdin.write(bytearray.fromhex(format(x, 'x')))
```

An even better way that spares the double conversion is:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["cat"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
x = [ 0x80 ]
p.stdin.write(bytearray(x))
```

Comment: well, no, you can't convert `'\x80'` to `'80'` this has to be a general solution.  Let me update the question to make it less "minimalistic".

Comment: This works with any 1 byte value. `80` here is just an example. You could easily use `fe`

Comment: I updated the question.  Sorry if initially I was not clear what I meant.  I just tried to be minimal, perhaps too hard. Please take a look now, thank you.

Comment: no, that is the problem, on Python 3 it does not work: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`  And in any case `0x43` would not do the trick, it is important to work for a byte like `0x80` with high bit 1.

Comment: Thank you, this works now.  You seem very knowledgeable about Python, so can I ask you - what I want is something very simple, take a byte-size unsigned int, and write that byte out.  To do this, your solution requires formating to a string, and then back to bytes.  Is there no simpler way?

Comment: yes this is great, I just wanted to keep `x` as it is (because of course, it is really some bigger thing).  So, the best answer would be `p.stdin.write(bytearray([x]))` .  This is exactly what I needed.